# TextView размещен в CardView, не полностью виден длинный текст

Tags: java, android, android-layout

`TextView` размещен в `CardView`, не полностью виден длинный текст или иногда пропадает. Как лечить?

Comment: Покажите файл разметки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать бегущую строку в textView, в остальном нужно смотреть разметку и код.

#### Бегущая строка:

***(разметка)***

```
android:id="@+id/tvCapt"
android:singleLine="true"  
android:ellipsize="marquee"  
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"  
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

***(код)***

```java
TextView dCapt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCapt);
dCapt.setText("CAPTION_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG");
dCapt.setSelected(true);
```